# How to rewrite deprecated DDL() statement in SQLAlchemy 0.7+

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So far I have used the following statements in SQLAlchemy to implement table inheritance via ALTER TABLE:

`inherit = "ALTER TABLE %(fullname)s INHERIT parent_table"`

`DDL(inherit, on='postgresql').execute_at("after-create", child_table)`

This is deprecated in SQLAlchemy now, and I am a bit confused about the new method through
`DDLEvents`, `DDLElement.execute_if()`, listeners and events in general.

What is the correct way to create and execute `DDL()` constructs in SQLAlchemy 0.7+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [an example in documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/ddl.html#sqlalchemy.schema.DDL), your code can be rewritten as:

```
event.listen(child_table, "after-create", DDL(inherit).execute_if(dialect='postgresql'))
```